# Absurd MySQL behavior over same data set but different threads

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm connecting to MySQL db from two different PHP instances. The first thread adds a new row, passes the 'id' of new row to the second thread via a queue. *Sometimes* the second thread is unable to find the new row data, even though theoretically it should hit the db after first threads has finished its job.

The simplified pseudocode looks something like

Thread 1

```
$db = get_mysql_connection();
$db->beginTransaction();
$rowid = $db->query("insert data..");
$db->commit();

//For Debugging purposes only
$db->check_if_row_exists($rowid); //Always returns true

send_to_queue($rowid);
```

Thread 2

```
$rowid = fetch_from_queue();
$db = get_mysql_connection();
$db->check_if_row_exists($rowid); //Sometimes returns false;
usleep(1000000);
$db->check_if_row_exists($rowid); //Always returns true.
```

I cannot understand, why thread 1 shows that data has a valid entry, while thread 2, which certainly makes a query *sometime* after thread 1, is unable to find the data. I'm using transactions to commit the data, is that doing something weird?

I'm using Gearman as the queue. Thread 1 is run through Apache, while Thread 2 simply runs as a standalone process.

**Edit 1:**
This happens when thread 2 is running concurrently to thread 1. Apparently it reaches some race condition with Thread 1, but I can't figure out why.

**Edit 2:**
As pointed out by N.B., Innodb delays writing the data to disk, and hence it is not visible to second thread.

How should I handle this scenario? Sleep/Usleep is nearly always a suboptimal solution, as under heavy load conditions, the disk i/o time may increase. Is there some way to 'notify' the second thread that Innodb has finished its disk i/o?

Comment: Are you sure, `rowid` is always transfered successfully to another thread?

Comment: Yep. Notice the second `check_if_row_exists` call. It always returns true.

Comment: Please add the line to Thread 1 example where second thread is passed the id.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - `send_to_queue` is the mechanism that I'm using.

Comment: Can you see if any db errors are generated in your `check_if_row_exists` function?

Comment: @thetaiko - Nope. DB simply returns false, that is $rowid is currently not present in DB. If I wait for even 200 miliseconds, the $rowid becomes visible to second thread.

Comment: Transaction commit may be delayed, but for first row it exists inside transaction. Almost not used them, but `UPDATE` then `SELECT` sometimes are executed in different order even from one thread. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/01/11/when-does-innodb-start-transaction/

Comment: @Neo, the DB might be returning an error.  I know that PDO, by default, doesn't throw errors but you can see them if a `query` returns `false` by checking `$db->errorInfo()`

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ - We are using in house ORM, so there is some extra exception handling, abstraction etc. I can't see anything fishy.

Comment: There are no race conditions here. Thread 1 can see its transactions and data. Thread 2 can't because they haven't reached the disk yet (no fsync call has been made yet by InnoDB). So naturally, you'll always see data from thread 1, but if it's not on the disk at the time of calling - you won't see it within thread 2. Threads 1 and 2 don't share the SAME mysql connection thread, both use a different one. So to cut it short - if not on disk, no data available. It's not on disk because InnoDB will delay the write until the drive is ready to write. That's why you see it after usleep.

Comment: @thetaiko - Yea. I'll try digging deeper into the mysqli query that I' making.

Comment: @N.B. - That definitely looks to be the case, since even a delay of 200 miliseconds is sufficient to make the data visible. Yes, we use Innodb. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll edit the question to 'how to solve this problem'. Retry using 'while'?

Comment: Check your InnoDB settings (e.g.: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit). Depending on your setting, it's not guaranteed that the data will be flushed to disk right away. Changing these settings will most likely affect performance, so be careful.

Comment: Short answer to the question in regards to how to solve this - don't use MySQL as the queue and look for an alternative (not MongoDB or something similar but systems like ZeroMQ or similar).

Comment: What happens if on the second thread you issue a `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` query just prior to `check_if_row_exists()`?

Comment: @N.B. - We don't use mysql as queue. As I mentioned in the question, we use Gearman for queuing purposes. And even Gearman uses mysql(drizzle) for making queue data persistent. We don't need persistence though.

Comment: @N.B. - Can you post a solution so that I can mark that as an answer?

Comment: Posted as requested. Also, check ZeroMQ just for sake of learning about a new thing. It uses the disk for persistence if it runs out of memory, and it's very efficient in transferring the data and storing it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting from my comment seeing that there's no need to change anything:

> There are no race conditions here. Thread 1 can see its transactions
>   and data. Thread 2 can't because they haven't reached the disk yet (no
>   fsync call has been made yet by InnoDB). So naturally, you'll always
>   see data from thread 1, but if it's not on the disk at the time of
>   calling - you won't see it within thread 2. Threads 1 and 2 don't
>   share the SAME mysql connection thread, both use a different one. So
>   to cut it short - if not on disk, no data available. It's not on disk
>   because InnoDB will delay the write until the drive is ready to write.
>   That's why you see it after usleep.